# How to deal with pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: connection closed?

Tags: python, database-connection, pymongo

I am writing a python code to update each document in collection. My code is like:

```
for r, d_50 in enumerate(grid50.find().batch_size(500)):
    self_grid = grid50.find({'_id':d_50['_id']})
    .....
    .....
    (processing process)
    grid50.update({'_id':d_50['_id']},{'$set':{u'big_cell8':{"POI":venue_count, "cell_ids":cell_ids}}})
```

However, when I run this code, I met problem:

```
   raise AutoReconnect(str(e))
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: connection closed
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? Should I add something in my code to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

From PyMongo [Docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html) -

> exception pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect(message='', errors=None)
>
> Raised when a connection to the database is lost and an attempt to
>   auto-reconnect will be made.
>
> In order to auto-reconnect you must handle this exception, recognizing
>   that the operation which caused it has not necessarily succeeded.
>   Future operations will attempt to open a new connection to the
>   database (and will continue to raise this exception until the first
>   successful connection is made).

Basically you'll have to handle this exception so that the application reconnects to mongo and re-runs the function that failed..